# New dataframe: group by date, condition on time, sum values with if condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to find a "pandas" solution for this:

I have a dataframe with two columns, one for datetime and one for numeric values.

Assume this for the dataframe:

```
datarange=pd.date_range('01-05-2018 13:00:00', periods=12000, freq="1H")
range_series=pd.Series(np.random.randint(-2,2,size=12000).astype(float), index=datarange)
frame=pd.DataFrame(range_series, columns=['diffs'])
frame.index.name='datetime'
```

The output is something like this:

```
print(frame.head(10), frame.tail(10))

           datetime    diffs
2018-01-05 13:00:00   -2.0
2018-01-05 14:00:00    0.0
2018-01-05 15:00:00   -2.0
2018-01-05 16:00:00    1.0
2018-01-05 17:00:00    1.0
2018-01-05 18:00:00    1.0
2018-01-05 19:00:00   -1.0
2018-01-05 20:00:00   -2.0
2018-01-05 21:00:00   -2.0
2018-01-05 22:00:00   -2.0
Freq: H, dtype: float64
           datetime    diffs
2019-05-20 03:00:00   -1.0
2019-05-20 04:00:00   -1.0
2019-05-20 05:00:00    0.0
2019-05-20 06:00:00    1.0
2019-05-20 07:00:00    0.0
2019-05-20 08:00:00   -2.0
2019-05-20 09:00:00    1.0
2019-05-20 10:00:00   -1.0
2019-05-20 11:00:00    1.0
2019-05-20 12:00:00   -2.0
Freq: H, dtype: float64
```

I need to create a new dataframe with new columns:

new column A: sum of diffs for the same date from hour 5:00 to hour 21:00 if diffs.value>0

new column B: sum of diffs for the same date from hour 5:00 to hour 21:00 if diffs.value<0

new column C: sum of diffs if diffs.value>0 for the group 'y-m-d 22:00:00' to 'y-m-d+1 4:00:00'

new column D: sum of diffs if diffs.value<0 for the group 'y-m-d 22:00:00' to 'y-m-d+1 4:00:00'

So practically, 5 new columns:

1) date

2) to accommodate the sum of the positive diffs per day from hours 5 to 21

3) to accommodate the sum of the negative diffs per day from hours 5 to 21

4) to accommodate the sum of the positive diffs from 22:00 of one day to 4:00 of the next day

5) to accommodate the sum of the negative diffs from 22:00 of one day to 4:00 of the next day

I could start iterating over lists to create new lists and then bring them back together into a new dataframe. But I am trying to figure out if I could somehow groupby and apply criteria in different columns and aggregate.

Note: the sum as described in (4) and (5) should fall under the date of the day 1.

I would welcome your input. I am not a developer and definitely not experienced in pandas, but the library seems to offer huge possibilities, that I try to explore.

Hoping my description is clear, thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to post your code to receive better guidance. :) Plus, you should post a [mcve] instead of just ""what your data format is"".

Comment: Provide a snippet of your dataframe & expected output. That is likely to get you better response than ‚all text‘ question

Comment: Like the other comments. I think your question is pretty clear but make it easier for the people that are willing to help you and give code that can easily reproduce your dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it myself after all... and I post my code, but would welcome anyone with a cleaner, shorter and more elegant code.

Starting with this dataframe

```
dates=pd.date_range('01-05-2018 13:00:00', periods=12000, freq="1H")
range_series=pd.Series(np.random.randint(-2,2,size=12000).astype(float), index=dates)
df=pd.DataFrame(range_series, columns=['diffs'])
df.index.name='datetime'
```

I create a date and a time column:

```
df['date']=df.index.date
df['time']=df.index.time
```

I locate the new columns to the front (so that I am able to control my calculations):

```
new_df = df.iloc[:, np.r_[1,2,0]]
```

I create two different dataframes slicing the times I want each time:

```
day_df=new_df.between_time('05:00', '21:00')
night_df=new_df.between_time('22:00','04:00')
```

I groupby 'date' and I aggregate three methods (sum, sum if positive, sum if negative):

```
day_change=day_df.groupby(day_df['date'])['diffs'].\
        agg([('daytime change' , lambda x : x.sum()) ,\
             ('daytime negative change' , lambda x : x[x < 0].sum()) , \
             ('daytime positive change' , lambda x : x[x > 0].sum())])
night_change=night_df.groupby(night_df['date'])['diffs'].\
        agg([('nighttime change' , lambda x : x.sum()) ,\
             ('nighttime negative change' , lambda x : x[x < 0].sum()) , \
             ('nighttime positive change' , lambda x : x[x > 0].sum())])
```

I concatenate by the horizontal axis the two dataframes with an "inner join" just in case the number of rows of the two dataframes are not equal:

```
change=pd.concat([day_change,night_change], axis=1, join='inner')
```

And I get the desired output:

```
print(change.head(1))
            daytime change  daytime negative change  daytime positive change  \
date                                                                           
2018-01-05            -7.0                    -10.0                      3.0   

            nighttime change  nighttime negative change  \
date                                                      
2018-01-05               0.0                        0.0   

            nighttime positive change  
date                                   
2018-01-05                        0.0
```